# Spark SQL UDF returning scala immutable Map with df.WithColumn()

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql, udf

I have case class

```
case class MyCaseClass(City : String, Extras : Map[String, String])
```

and user defined function which returns scala.collection.immutable.Map

```
def extrasUdf = spark.udf.register(
   "extras_udf", 
   (age : Int, name : String) => Map("age" -> age.toString, "name" -> name)
)
```

but this breaks with Exception:

```
import spark.implicits._

spark.read.options(...).load(...)
      .select('City, 'Age, 'Name)
      .withColumn("Extras", extrasUdf('Age, 'Name))
      .drop('Age)
      .drop('Name)
      .as[MyCaseClass]
```

I should use spark sql's MapType(DataTypes.StringType, DataTypes.IntegerType)
but I can't find any working example...

And this works if I use scala.collection.Map but I need immutable Map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many problems with your code:

- You are using `def extrastUdf =`, which creates a function for registering a UDF as opposed to actually creating/registering a UDF. Use `val extrasUdf =` instead.
- You are mixing value types in your map (`String` and `Int`), which makes the map be `Map[String, Any]` as `Any` is the common superclass of `String` and `Int`. Spark does not support `Any`. You can do at least two things: (a) switch to using a string map (with `age.toString`, in which case you don't need a UDF as you can simply use [`map()`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)) or (b) switch to using named structs using [`named_struct()`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) (again, without the need for a UDF). As a rule, only write a UDF if you cannot do what you need to do with the existing functions. I prefer to look at the Hive documentation because the Spark docs are rather sparse.
- Also, keep in mind that type specification in Spark schema (e.g., `MapType`) is completely different from Scala types (e.g., `Map[_, _]`) and separate from how types are represented internally and mapped between Scala & Spark data structures. In other words, this has nothing to do with mutable vs. immutable collections.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it possible without/with UDF to put inside WithColumn() expression to put 'Age, 'Name in map only if they are not null cause I don't want to have null values in map?

Comment: You could use `if()` or a `case when ... then` expression.